# Sum values within a time frame

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

[image]I have 550 rows of data that represent daily flight times. Each flight, depending on aircraft type, requires a certain number of people to attend the flight. That task takes 45 minutes.  So at any given flight time, there will be people busy with that flight plus any flights within the prior 45 minutes.  I want to get an aggregate count of the total people required at any flight time.  I also want to treat the 45 minutes as an input variable to see how changes to this task time affect the manpower demand at each flight time.

Here is a mockup of what the data looks like:

```
     A            B         C.        D
1   2:30          4        0:45       4
2   2:45          3.                  7
3   3:15          2.                  9
4   3:30          4.                  9
5   3:35          5.                 11
```

Column A contains the flight times.  Column B contains the number of people required for that flight.  Cell C1 contains the value for the task time.  I want to fill in column D with the aggregate count of staff required at each flight time.  The example is shown with the results filled in.

A sample calculation would look like this.  Use row 4 as an example.  The flight time is 3:30.  Based on a 45 minute task time, all flights on or after 2:45 would require concurrently active people.  There are three such flights, 2:45, 3:15, and 3:30.  The staffing from column B for those flights is 3, 2, and 4, so the total staffing requirement at the time of the 3:30 flight is 9.  That's what goes in D4.

If I was to change the task time in C1 to 30 minutes, only the 3:15 and 3:30 flights would qualify, so the total in D4 would be 6.

I have tried `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS`. I have added a row with the data (time) minus `C1` then tried to sum everything in `B` between that time range. I can't seem to get the `B` column to add the data.

I tried

```
    =sumif(A:A,"<=A4",B:B)-sumif(A:A,"<=A4-C1",B:B)
```

Comment: You're giving the `0:45` variable, where is the variable of `3:30` coming from? Is the formula always going to work back from `3:30`?

Comment: @CharlieRB: He says in the question that `3:30` is coming from cell `A4`. Why he's using `A4` as his example, what he wants done on rows 1, 2, and 3, and what the relationship between `A4` and `C1` is, remain as mysteries.

Comment: @CharlesT: Don't apologize for not being able to comment; clarifications to the question ***should*** be submitted as edits to the question. Click on the "flag" link and ask to have your two accounts merged, so you can edit the your question directly without going through peer review. Then try to explain what you want more clearly. It might help if you included an illustration of the complete sheet, as you want it.

Comment: Can you share the formula you tried for both `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS`?

Comment: Please contact Stack Exchange having your accounts merged: http://superuser.com/contact

Comment: When you say `"<=A4"`, `SUMIF` sees a criteria specification of `"<=A4"`, which doesn't make any sense. If you want to select rows whose value is ≤ 3:30, try `"<=" & A4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution.  This is the formula for D1.  Enter it and then copy down for other cells in D:

```
    =SUM(INDIRECT("b"&IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1-C$1,A$1:A1,0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1-C$1,A$1:A1,1)),1,MATCH(A1-C$1,A$1:A1,1)+1),MATCH(A1-C$1,A$1:A1,0))):B1)
```

This is basically the logic.  It finds the first row that meets your criteria and then sums the values in B between there and the current row.  The way it finds the first row is by using the MATCH function to compare the time in col A minus the time in C1 to the time values in the rows up to and including the current row.  MATCH doesn't have a GE lookup for values in ascending order, so this uses a combination of LE and EQ.

- If there is nothing LT, that means row 1 is GE, so that is the first row.
- If a row is EQ, that is the starting row.
- If a row is LE but not EQ, that means the next row is the first GE, so that is the first row.

Comment: Wow...it worked. You legend. With my little excel knowledge I actually understand that.

Comment: Sorry it won't let be edit my last comment. I pressed enter to go down a line. Wow...it worked. You legend. With my little excel knowledge I actually understand that. thank you so much. One thing it's doing though is its suming the first set of data outside of the range. Example it's 2:00 on my spreadsheet which should sum everything between 1:45 & 2:00. What's it's doing is picking up the data at 1:10. This is the first set of data outside of the range. Do you know anything that would fix that? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is a great question that's not as unique as it first appeared.  I don't think you're the only person with this type of problem.  I think it got downvoted because it was hard to follow, particularly before you added some clarification.  I submitted some edits to make it easier to understand.

Comment: If you are still using 45 minutes, the range should start at 1:15.  However, 1:10 is still outside the range.  I tested it against conditions like that and it worked.  I'm wondering if, in the process of copying, one of the ranges got corrupted.  Look at the formula in the cell that is messing up and verify that the ranges are correct.

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a mistype the range should have been 1:15-2:00. I,m trying to locate it but can't. I have had to add a few cell locks as I'm dragging over different ranges. Maybe that's where it's not working.

Comment: I added a photo to original question

Comment: In this case, I'm not sure the photo helps to understand the problem.  You can see a lot of data, but the visible part doesn't match the simplified description.  It might just add confusion, trying to find the example on the screen image.  As it's explained, I think people will be able to understand it.